# Rally Kanban # of days since first state?

Tags: rally, kanban

Is there a way to calculate the number of days since the card has been in the first state?  Lets use say I use a custom field \for the kanban states.  1,2,3,4  If a card is in state 3 then how long has it been since # 1?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of a way to automate it or flag items but if you review the US/DE in question just take a quick look at the revision history.

Any changes in state should be logged in the history.

Answer (score 0):

Use Lookback API to access historic data.

Lookback API allows to see what any work item or collection of work items looked like in the past. This is different from using WS API directly, which can provide you with the current state of objects, but does not have historical data.

LBAPI documentation is available [here](https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc)

Here is an example that builds a grid of stories with a Kanban state. When a story's row is double-clicked, the time this story has spent in three Kanban states is calculated and a grid is built to show the values:

[image]

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    launch: function(){
        var x = Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore', {
                fetch    : ['Name','c_Kanban','_UnformattedID', '_TypeHierarchy'],
                filters  : [{
                    property : '__At',
                    value    : 'current'
                },
                {
                    property : '_TypeHierarchy',
                    value    : 'HierarchicalRequirement'
                },
               {
                    property : '_ProjectHierarchy',
                    value    :   22222
                },
                {
                property : 'c_Kanban', //get stories with Kanban state
                operator : 'exists',
                value : true
                }
                ],
                hydrate: ['_TypeHierarchy', 'c_Kanban'],
                listeners: {
                    load: this.onStoriesLoaded, 
                    scope: this
                }
                }).load({
                    params : {
                        compress : true,
                        removeUnauthorizedSnapshots : true
                    }
                });

    },
     //make grid of stories with Kanban state
     onStoriesLoaded: function(store, data){
        var that = this;
        var stories = [];
        var id;
        Ext.Array.each(data, function(record) {
            var artifactType =  record.get('_TypeHierarchy');
            if (artifactType[artifactType.length - 1] == "HierarchicalRequirement") {
                id = 'US' + record.get('_UnformattedID');
            } else if (artifactType[artifactType.length - 1] == "Defect") {
                id = 'DE' + record.get('_UnformattedID');
            } 
            stories.push({
                Name: record.get('Name'),
                FormattedID: id,
                UnformattedID: record.get('_UnformattedID'),
                c_Kanban: record.get('c_Kanban')
            });
            console.log(stories);
            });

            var myStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                data: stories
            });

            if (!this.down('#allStoriesGrid')) {
                this.add({
                    xtype: 'rallygrid',
                    id: 'allStoriesGrid',
                    store: myStore,
                    width: 500,
                    columnCfgs: [
                        {
                            text: 'Formatted ID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID',
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name', flex: 1,
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Kanban', dataIndex: 'c_Kanban'
                        }
                    ],
                    listeners: {
                        celldblclick: function( grid, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex){
                            id = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex).get('UnformattedID');
                            console.log('id', id);
                            that.getStoryModel(id);      //to eventually build a grid of Kanban allowed values 
                            }
                    }
                });
            }else{
                this.down('#allStoriesGrid').reconfigure(myStore);
            }
     },

     getStoryModel:function(id){
        console.log('get story model');
        var that = this;
        this.arr=[];
        //get a model of user story
        Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
            type: 'User Story',
            context: {
                workspace: '/workspace/11111',
                project: 'project/22222'    
            },
            success: function(model){
                //Get store instance for the allowed values
                var allowedValuesStore = model.getField('c_Kanban').getAllowedValueStore( );
                that.getDropdownValues(allowedValuesStore, id);
            }

        });
     },


     getDropdownValues:function(allowedValuesStore, id){
        var that = this;
        //load data into the store
        allowedValuesStore.load({
            scope: this,
            callback: function(records, operation, success){
                _.each(records, function(val){
                    //AllowedAttributeValue object in WS API has StringValue
                    var v = val.get('StringValue');
                    that.arr.push(v);
                });
                console.log('arr', this.arr);
                that.getStoryById(id);    //former makeStore
            }
        });
    },

    getStoryById:function(id){
        var that = this;
        var snapStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore', {
            fetch: ['c_Kanban', 'Blocked'],
            hydrate:['c_Kanban','Blocked'],
             filters : [
                {
                    property : '_UnformattedID',
                    value    : id  //15  
                }
            ],
            sorters:[
                {
                    property  : '_ValidTo',
                    direction : 'ASC'
                }
            ]
        });
        snapStore.load({
            params: {
                compress: true,
                removeUnauthorizedSnapshots : true
            },
             callback : function(records, operation, success) {
                that.onDataLoaded(records, id);
            }
        });
    },

    onDataLoaded:function(records, id){
        var times = [];
        var measure = 'second';

        //-----------------------backlog

        var backlog = _.filter(records, function(record) {
                    return record.get('c_Kanban') === 'backlog';
        });
        console.log('backlog',backlog);
        var cycleTimeFromBacklogToInProgress = '';
        if (_.size(backlog) > 0) {
            var backlog1 = _.first(backlog);
            var backlog2 = _.last(backlog);
            var backlogDate1 = new Date(backlog1.get('_ValidFrom'));
            if (backlog2.get('_ValidTo') === "9999-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") { //infinity
                backlogDate2 = new Date(); //now
            }
            else{
                var backlogDate2 = new Date(backlog2.get('_ValidTo'));
            }

            cycleTimeFromBacklogToInProgress = Rally.util.DateTime.getDifference(backlogDate2,backlogDate1, measure );
        }
        times.push(cycleTimeFromBacklogToInProgress);
        //console.log(cycleTimeFromBacklogToInProgress);

        //----------------------in progress


        var inProgress = _.filter(records, function(record) {
                    return record.get('c_Kanban') === 'in-progress';
        });
        console.log('in-progress',inProgress);
        var cycleTimeFromInProgressToDone = '';
        if (_.size(inProgress) > 0) {
            var inProgress1 = _.first(inProgress);
            var inProgress2 = _.last(inProgress);
            var inProgressDate1 = new Date(inProgress1.get('_ValidFrom'));
            if (inProgress2.get('_ValidTo') === "9999-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") { //infinity
                inProgressDate2 = new Date(); //now
            }
            else{
                var inProgressDate2 = new Date(inProgress2.get('_ValidTo'));
            }
            cycleTimeFromInProgressToDone = Rally.util.DateTime.getDifference(inProgressDate2,inProgressDate1, measure );
        }
        times.push(cycleTimeFromInProgressToDone);
        //console.log(cycleTimeFromInProgressToDone);


        //------------------------done

        var done = _.filter(records, function(record) {
                    return record.get('c_Kanban') === 'done';
        });
        console.log('done',done);
        var cycleTimeFromDoneToReleased = '';
        if (_.size(done) > 0) {
            var done1 = _.first(done);
            var done2 = _.last(done);
            var doneDate1 = new Date(done1.get('_ValidFrom'));
            if (done2.get('_ValidTo') === "9999-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") { //infinity
                doneDate2 = new Date(); //now
            }
            else{
                var doneDate2 = new Date(done2.get('_ValidTo'));
            }
            cycleTimeFromDoneToReleased = Rally.util.DateTime.getDifference(doneDate2,doneDate1, measure );
        }
        times.push(cycleTimeFromDoneToReleased);
        //console.log(cycleTimeFromDoneToReleased);


        /**********
        skip first '' element of the this.arr and last 'released' element of this.arr because
        do not care for cycle times in first and last kanban states
        Originally: arr ["", "backlog", "in-progress", "done", "released"] ,shorten to: ["backlog", "in-progress", "done"]

        **********/

        this.arrShortened = _.without(this.arr, _.first(this.arr),_.last(this.arr)) ;
        console.log('this.arrShortened with first and last skipped', this.arrShortened); //["backlog", "in-progress", "done"] 

        cycleTimes = _.zip(this.arrShortened, times);
        //console.log('cycleTimes as multi-dimentional array', cycleTimes);

        cycleTimes = _.object(cycleTimes);
        //console.log('cycleTimes as object', cycleTimes); //cycleTimes as object Object {backlog: 89, in-progress: 237, done: 55} 

        var cycleTimesArray = [];

        cycleTimesArray.push(cycleTimes);

        console.log('cycleTimesArray',cycleTimesArray);

         var store = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store',{
            data: cycleTimesArray, 
            pageSize: 100
        });


        var columnConfig = [];
        _.each(cycleTimes,function(c,key){
            var columnConfigElement = _.object(['text', 'dataIndex', 'flex'], ['time spent in ' + key, key, 1]);
            columnConfig.push(columnConfigElement);
        });

        var title = 'Kanban cycle time for US' + id + ' in ' + measure + 's'
        if (!this.grid) {
            this.grid = this.add({
                xtype: 'rallygrid',
                title: title,
                width: 500,
                itemId: 'grid2',
                store: store,
                columnCfgs: columnConfig
            });
         }
         else{
            this.down('#grid2').reconfigure(store);
         }
    }

});
```

Comment: Nick is this code I can place into a Custom HTML App?  When I copy it in and save it just shows the code.

Comment: This is a js file. You need to copy a full html file. A variation of this code (and the full html) is found here: https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/caclulate-cycle-time-kanban/tree/master/deploy Please note this is not a supported catalog app, but a coding example you may customize further.